# SQL*Plus ignores colsep option

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

So we are trying to dump the content of our oracle database to a .CSV file but when executing the following command

```sql
set colsep ',' echo off newpage 0 space 0 pagesize 0 linesize 3000 feed off head off trimspool on 
spool C:\Users\whocares\Desktop\test.CSV
select ID, LOCATION_ID from club; 
spool off
```

the output looks as follows:

```
...


     17499        902
     17500        902
     17501        902
     17502        902
     17503        902
     17504        902
     17505        902
     17506        902
     17507        902
     17508        902
     17509        902

...
```

and sqlplus seems to completely ignore the `set colsep ','` option.
To get a valid `csv` output we need to have the output look like this:

```
...

17499,902
17500,902
17501,902
17502,902
17503,902
17504,902
17505,902
17506,902
17507,902
17508,902
17509,902

...
```

So how do you properly use the `set colsep` option?
We don't have much experience with sqlplus and for some reason [other stackoverflow solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407396/sql-plus-output-is-not-coming-in-proper-csv-format-if-we-use-the-colsep) didn't seem to work for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET COLSEP` replaces `SET SPACE`, and that's so since Oracle 9.2 (see [Obsolete SQL*Plus Commands](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/apc.htm#634746)).

If you use them both, there's no separator:

```
SQL> set colsep ','
SQL> select * from dept where rownum = 1;

    DEPTNO,DNAME               ,LOC
----------,--------------------,--------------------
        10,ACCOUNTING          ,NEW YORK

SQL> set space 0
SQL> select * from dept where rownum = 1;

    DEPTNODNAME               LOC
--------------------------------------------------
        10ACCOUNTING          NEW YORK
    
SQL> set space 1
SQL> select * from dept where rownum = 1;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK

SQL>
```

So - remove `SET SPACE`.

---

Another option is to **concatenate** columns. Yes, that's a tedious job but it works, e.g.

```
SQL> select deptno ||','|| dname ||','|| loc from dept;

DEPTNO||','||DNAME||','||LOC
---------------------------------------------------------------
10,ACCOUNTING,NEW YORK
20,RESEARCH,DALLAS
30,SALES,CHICAGO
40,OPERATIONS,BOSTON

SQL>
```

If there are many tables involved, you could write a query which will write a query for you:

```
SQL> select 'select ' || listagg(column_name, '||'',''||') within group (order by column_id) ||
  2         ' from '  || table_name result
  3  from user_tab_columns
  4  where table_name = 'DEPT'
  5  group by table_name;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select DEPTNO||','||DNAME||','||LOC from DEPT

SQL>
```

Now just copy/paste the *result* and run it.

Comment: Ah alright. That works. However our database contains many empty columns and removing `SET SPACE` produces a bunch of spaces between the `,`(commas) for the empty fields. In order to reduce file size: is there really no way we can combine `SET SPACE` and `SET COLSEP` or would we have to run some script on the output csv file to remove these unwanted spaces?

Comment: I've added some more info. Have a look, please.